# Calling OLAP BAPI from C++

Tags: c++, mdx, saprfc, bapi, sap-bw

I am trying to use [SAP OLAP BAPI](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/64/9b8f3c855f0454e10000000a11405a/content.htm?frameset=/en/39/2c9b3c682a420ae10000000a114084/frameset.htm) for a very simple task. I want to connect to a SAP BW server, send an MDX query, get the result and disconnect. While I seem to have no problems connecting and disconnecting from the server, sending a query and retrieving results seem to be rather non-trivial tasks that I am seeking help with.

According to the SAP documentation, I need to use `MDDataSetBW` object, by first creating the query object using `CreateObject` and then retrieving the results using `GetAxisInfo` and `GetCellData`.

Right now I am stuck at the very first step of just creating the query object. The documentation states that `CreateObject` has one import parameter `CommandText` and two export parameters `DataSetID` and `Return`. The problem is that according to [SAP Documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/59/52cb84ea8d9a4582ca0af6328ba6de/content.htm) `CommandText` parameter is a table with a single column called `LINE`.

So basically it's just an MDX query, with each line of the query being a value of the `LINE` column of each row of this table. The question is how do I pass it? Can anyone point me to a C++ example code that does something like this?

Here's my current prototype code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

RFC_HANDLE Logon() 
{ 
    RFC_CONNOPT_R3ONLY conn_options;
    conn_options.hostname = SAP_LOGON::Hostname; 
    conn_options.sysnr = 0; 
    conn_options.gateway_host = nullptr; 
    conn_options.gateway_service = nullptr;

    RFC_OPTIONS options;
    options.mode = RFC_MODE_R3ONLY; 
    options.destination = SAP_LOGON::Destination; 
    options.client = SAP_LOGON::Client; 
    options.user = SAP_LOGON::User; 
    options.password = SAP_LOGON::Password; 
    options.language = SAP_LOGON::Language; 
    options.trace = 0; 
    options.connopt = &conn_options;

    RFC_HANDLE hConn = RfcOpen(&options);

    if (hConn == RFC_HANDLE_NULL)
        ErrorHandler(_T("RfcOpen"));

    return hConn;
} 

void MakeStringParam(RFC_PARAMETER& param, rfc_char_t* name, rfc_char_t* buf, unsigned long size)
{
    param.name = name;
    param.nlen = (unsigned int)wcslen(name);
    param.type = TYPC;
    param.leng = size;
    param.addr = &buf;
}

RFC_HANDLE WIN_DLL_EXPORT_FLAGS CreateQuery(RFC_HANDLE hConn, rfc_char_t* query) 
{
    rfc_char_t datasetID[256];
    rfc_char_t ret[256];

    RFC_PARAMETER exporting[3];
    MakeStringParam(exporting[0], _T("DataSetID"), datasetID, 256);
    MakeStringParam(exporting[1], _T("Return"), ret, 256);
    exporting[2].name = nullptr;

    // TODO: is it needed?
    RFC_PARAMETER importing[2]; 
    MakeStringParam(importing[0], _T("CommandText"), ret, 256);
    importing[1].name = nullptr;

    // TODO: put query into the table parameter
    RFC_TABLE tables[2]; 
    tables[0].name = _T("CommandText");
    tables[1].name = nullptr;
    rfc_char_t* ex = nullptr;

    RFC_RC rc = RfcCallReceive(hConn, _T("BAPI_MDDATASETBW_CREATE_OBJECT"), exporting, importing, tables, &ex); 

    if (rc == RFC_OK)
    {
        // TODO: retrieve query handle here
        RFC_HANDLE result = RFC_HANDLE_NULL;
        return result;
    }

    return RFC_HANDLE_NULL; 
} 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    RfcInit();

    RFC_HANDLE hConn = Logon();

    rfc_char_t* query = _T("\
        SELECT\
            {[Measures].[DA70CEZJ18267Q9RS4XFK7J32]} ON COLUMNS,\
            {[0APO_LOCNO].[LEVEL01].AllMembers} ON ROWS\
        FROM [0APO_C01/IDES_APO_04]");

    RFC_HANDLE hQuery = CreateQuery(hConn, query);

    // TODO: retrieve query results using 
    // - MDDataSetBW.GetAxisData
    // - MDDataSetBW.GetAxisInfo
    // - MDDataSetBW.GetCellData

    RfcClose(hConn);
    return 0;
}
```